# Importing data from arduino to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I am trying to import data from my arduino to python so that I can then use it in my program but I cannot find how to send the data without importing **b'\r\n'** as well.
This is an example of what I am currently importing:

> b'197,2302,50,198,\r\n'

# The numbers in the middle are data from four distance sensors

Comment: What's the problem of getting `b'197,2302,50,198,\r\n'?` Just strip() what you don't need from inside Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Arduino is probably sending the data with b'\r\n' in it.

You can get the numbers out with this regular expression like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[0-9]+', "b'197,2302,50,198,\r\n'")
['197', '2302', '50', '198']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question a few days ago. Maybe this thread helps you:
[pyserial communication with arduino (for motor-control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391672/pyserial-communication-with-arduino-for-motor-control?noredirect=1#comment68036285_40391672)

Just add this lines to read from serial and delete \r\n from your code:

```python
get = ser.readline()[:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how to send the data from arduino side, so I will answer dealing with the data you got; strip trailing space using `bytes.rstrip`:

```
>>> b'197,2302,50,198,\r\n'.rstrip()
b'197,2302,50,198,'
```